# Custom Prototype Cells - Storyboard Compilation Error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating custom prototype cells in my program, but I am unable to get the program to compile.
Here's what it looks like (i've kept it fairly standard right now, just to get it working):

[image: custom cells]

I have also created a new custom class homeTable, here's what homeTable.h looks like:

```
@interface homeTable : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *itemName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *itemType;

@end
```

I've set the tableViewCell to have a the custom class homeTable.

And here is what the code in my masterViewController looks like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"KeyCell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSDictionary *key = [ownedItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *name = [key objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *type = [key objectForKey:@"type"];

cell.itemName.text = name;
cell.itemType.text = type;

return cell;
}
```

When I try running the program it throws up a `Interface Builder Storyboard Compilation failed` error.
[image: error]

I've been stuck on this since yesterday, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and where is the error ?

Comment: Oops, it's in the subject, I added it to the post as well. The error is Interface Builder Storyboard Compilation failed

Comment: you need to post full error, probably with screenshot too

Comment: Have you set your tableViewCell as homeTable in your storyboard? by the way, you should yo set as homeTable and not as UITableViewCell your custom cell in your method cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: It's just this. There is nothing in the console, just this in the issue navigator. Added the screenshot to the main post.

Comment: Have you tried to disconnect the outlets and then compile? What happens?

Comment: Have you tried a clean build/cleaning the build folder, (option click clean)?

Comment: If you are getting a cell from the storyboard you don't need to do the check for `if (cell == nil)` and the allocation a new cell.

Comment: Your class cell name is 'homeTable', are you sure you put the same in the storyboard, maybe you added an upper Case H 'HomeTable', this should cause the failure.

Answer (score 0):

I may have miss a bigger issue but are here a few things that you could have done wrong.

First make sure your custom class and the cell identifier are correctly set-up in your storyboard.
Also right click on the tableViewController in the left panel inside the storyboard to take a look at your IB connections. You may have linked something you deleted later. You may see links with a ! telling you somethings isn't right.

Then you could change things in :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

First with storyboard no need for :

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Since cell will never be nil. Storyboard takes care of it, put a breakpoint there you'll see.

Also you are trying to access your custom properties

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *itemName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *itemType;
```

Without specifying the matching class, I would recommend you use your custom tableViewCell class as follow :

```
homeTable *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

By the way the name of your class should respect naming conventions. (But that will not help with your issue, just good practices).

If you still have a problem, I would recommend you post more details about what's going on in your storyboard.